# How to use Hilt and Mvvm?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have MVVM architecture in my app. Every screen where I would like to make a request to the api has such code scope:

```
val retrofitService = RetrofitService.getInstance(requireContext())
val mainRepository = MainRepository(retrofitService)
val viewModel =
ViewModelProvider(
viewOwner,
AppVMFactory(mainRepository)
)[AppViewModel::class.java]
```

and due to the fact that I have a lot of screens in the app I have a lot of similar code parts. In such case as I understood I can use Dependency Injection. I found [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldeIEXu2-2w) with provided [sample_project](https://github.com/mitchtabian/MVVMRecipeApp/tree/hilt-jetpack-compose) where got some info for support hilt in the app. I added all dependencies for hilt and then added application class and AppModule class:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule{
    @Singleton
    fun provideApp(@ApplicationContext app: Context):BaseApplication = app as BaseApplication

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun someStr() = "Hello World from DI"
}
```

in my test activity I added such lines:

```
@Inject
lateinit var str: String

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        println("Test $str")

        .....
}
```

and I got string for the AppModule object. Then the next step was adding returning method with AppViewModel:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule{
....
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun vmSupport(context: Context, owner: ViewModelStoreOwner): AppViewModel {
        val retrofitService = RetrofitService.getInstance(context)
        val mainRepository = MainRepository(retrofitService)
        return ViewModelProvider(
            owner,
            AppVMFactory(mainRepository)
        )[AppViewModel::class.java]
    }
....

}
```

but during my build I got this error:

```
[Dagger/MissingBinding] android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements HiltWrapper_ActivityRetainedComponentManager_ActivityRetainedComponentBuilderEntryPoint,
                         ^
      android.content.Context is injected at
          pkg.di.AppModule.vmSupport(context, …)
      pkg.viewModel.AppViewModel is injected at
          pkg.HomeScreen.vm
      pkg.HomeScreen is injected at
          pkg.HomeScreen_GeneratedInjector.injectHomeScreen(pkg.HomeScreen) [pkg.di.BaseApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC → pkg.di.BaseApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → pkg.di.BaseApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC]
```

and I also added such line to the test activity:

```
@Inject
lateinit var vm:AppViewModel
```

As I understood the problem is connected with passing arguments to the function, but how I can do it via hilt and so on? Or I did it in totally wrong way? My VM class you can see below:

```
class AppViewModel(private val mainRepository: MainRepository) : ViewModel(){...}
```

And MainRepository:

```
class MainRepository constructor(private val retrofitService: RetrofitService){...}
```

and retrofit service is simple interface.

### update

My factory for viewmodel:

```
class AppVMFactory(private val repository: MainRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(AppViewModel::class.java)) {
            AppViewModel(this.repository) as T
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("ViewModel Not Found")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That video is nearly a couple years old - I'd say it is mostly out of date, and may or may not be credible - removal of the dislike youtube button makes it hard to gauge.  Refer to the documentation as a starting point : https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android - it is well documented with a lot of detail as Google advocates you to use Dagger/Hilt as there preferred DI choice for JVM/Android only apps.

Comment: @Markm. yes sure, I saw this docs from Google, already added it to the app, but the problem is with adding support of my VM :( little bit difficult to understand what I need for it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to have a method with the @Provides annotation for all or almost all the parameters that you will pass in the other @Provider methods. In this case, the error is self-explanatory. You pass the Context as a parameter, but you don't have a method that makes the Provider of the Context. You needed something like this:

```
interface ContextProvider {
    fun getLatestContext(): Context
}

/**
 * Provider to give the current available context to be possible to inject
 * the context inside classes
 */
class ContextProviderImpl @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) :
    Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks,
    ContextProvider {

    private var currentActivityRef: WeakReference<Activity> = WeakReference(null)

    override fun getLatestContext(): Context {
        return currentActivityRef.get() ?: context
    }

    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {
        // not used
    }

    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {
        currentActivityRef = WeakReference(activity)
    }

    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
        currentActivityRef = WeakReference(activity)
    }

    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {
        if (activity === currentActivityRef.get()) {
            currentActivityRef = WeakReference(null)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, p1: Bundle) {
        // not used
    }

    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {
        // not used
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, p1: Bundle?) {
        currentActivityRef = WeakReference(activity)
    }
}
```

And after that the Provider method for the context. It is very important that you return the Interface and not the implementation, but that this method provides the implementation and not the interface. Take a look at the code:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ProviderModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContextProvider(context: Context): ContextProvider =
        ContextProviderImpl(context)
}
```

Comment: You don't need ViewModelStoreOwner and ViewModelFactory if you instantiate viewModel with by viewModels(). Something like this:
private val dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel by viewModels() and in ViewModel you should have @HiltViewModel annotation and all the parameters should have a provider method.

Comment: Take a look at this if you want: https://mahendranv.github.io/posts/hilt-viewmodel/ . Has a better explanation with examples of what am I saying. Besides that, your viewModel should never know about the Context.

Comment: Yes, you need the HiltViewModel annotation in your ViewModel and the Inject annotation before the constructor keyword. In your viewModel, if you receive a repository instance or anything else, you need to have a Provider method for that. The connection between the things is very abstract, is Hilt that handles it.

Comment: Since you don't need ViewModelFactory class, you don't need ViewModelStoreOwner.

Comment: so in such case I won't need to pass it as parameter to my function in AppModule class? As I see we need only to provide all parts for view model in AppModule and then viewmodel will be available for all app fragments ?

Comment: You don't need it. You don't even need a @Provider for the ViewModel. by viewModels does this for you.

Comment: In your viewModel, you need something like this: @ HiltViewModel class MyViewModel @ Inject constructor(private val anythingYouNeed: AnythingYouNeed) {} and in your fragment or activity, you just do: private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels() . You only need to make a provider method for the parameter anythingYouNeed.

Comment: Why not? I only used it in fragments and never got problems

Comment: But why you need ViewModelFactory?

Comment: without it I will get error `Cannot create an instance of class pkg.AppViewModel`

Comment: For making the request, you need the repository right? So, you need to make a provider method like this: 
@ Module
@ InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {

    @ Provides
    @ Singleton
    fun providesJobOffersRepository(jobOffersService: JobOffersService) =
        JobOffersRepository(jobOffersService)
}

Comment: Instead of passing the service by parameter, you can create it inside of the method

Comment: here is the latest attempts - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73344581/how-to-use-hilt-with-mvvm-in-fragments